# Gradle: Filter and execute tasks from a given task

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, travis-ci

I want to run ./gradlew verifyProjectDebug to run a subset of verification tasks.

verifyProjectDebug tries to extract a subset of the tasks in the project and execute them.

```
static def isValidTask(String name) {
    def isLint = name.matches("lint.*Debug")
    def isKtlint = name.matches("ktlint.*Debug.*Check")
    def isUnitTest = name.matches("test((?!Prod|Staging).)*DebugUnitTest")

    return (isLint || isKtlint || isUnitTest) && !name.contains("Prod")
}

task verifyProjectDebug() {
    group = "verification"
    description = "Runs lint, ktlint and tests for all debug non-production variants"

    doLast {
        getSubprojects()
                .collect { it.tasks }
                .flatten()
                .findAll { isValidTask(it.name) }
                .each { it.execute() }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, calling .execute() on a task does not invoke its dependencies so some of the tasks fails because its dependencies were not invoked.

Is there any way in gradle I can achieve this. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this in the project level gradle file did the trick.

```
task verifyDebugProjects() {
    group = "verification"
    description = "Runs lint, ktlint and tests for all debug non-production variants"
}

static def isValidVerifyDebugTask(String name) {
    def isLint = name.matches("lint.*Debug")
    def isKtlint = name.matches("ktlint.*Debug.*Check")
    def isUnitTest = name.matches("test((?!Prod|Staging).)*DebugUnitTest")

    return (isLint || isKtlint || isUnitTest) && !name.contains("Prod")
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    getSubprojects()
            .collect { it.tasks }
            .flatten()
            .findAll { isValidVerifyDebugTask(it.name) }
            .each { verifyDebugProjects.dependsOn it }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`execute` is a method of the `Task` class. You're trying to bypass Gradle build system. Executing tasks is not a simple matter or creating an instance and calling `execute`. Gradle handles dependency injection, caching, input & output processing, all kinds of stuff. So leverage Gradle.

### 1)

Create one *lifecycle task* that is the parent task for everything you want to execute.

```
final def verifyProject = tasks.register("verifyProject")
```

Lifecycle task is a task that doesn't do any work, it only depends on other tasks.

### 2)

You can only reference tasks that are already created. For example you can't reference lint task of the debug variant until the debug variant is created.

Process each variant when it's created, find all tasks you want executed and connect them to the master task.

```
android.applicationVariants.all {
    final def cappedVariantName = name.capitalize()

    // For every build variant that has build type "debug"...
    if (variant.buildType == "debug") {
        verifyProject.configure {
            dependsOn("lint$cappedVariantName")
            dependsOn("ktlint$cappedVariantName")
            dependsOn("test${cappedVariantName}UnitTest")
        }
    }
}
```

Please verify the names of tasks you want executed.

Now ehen you run `gradlew verifyProject` all the tasks this task depends on will get executed. You're in charge of the dependencies.

If you want to use this in an Android library module replace `android.applicationVariants` with `android.libraryVariants`.

The code follows [Task Conviguration Avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html). This means the tasks you defined won't be configured unless you specifically invoke them. This should save resources (CPU & memory) when running a build.

### 3)

To do this automatically for all modules pick one or both of the following, and put to to your *root project* `build.gradle`.

```
subprojects { project ->
    project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        // For all libraries and only libraries:
        if (plugin instanceof com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin) {
            project.android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
                // See above.
            }
        }
        // For all apps and only apps:
        if (plugin instanceof com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin) {
            project.android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                // See above.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a multi module project, and I don't want to add code to all build.gradle files for each module. Is there something I can do that only changes the project level build.gradle?

Comment: @TusharNallan Sure, check now. You could probably refactor the common code but that's beyond the scope.

Comment: Inside the subprojects, is it possible to get a callback after all the tasks have been generated? That was I can just check the task Name instead of the variant logic?

This solved my problem already, but trying to understand gradle more.

Comment: I dont think so, the collection of variants is potentially infinite, so there's no callback at the end. The `variant` object has a lot of task providers as properties so you don't have to find them by name.

Comment: Oh, and a great source if you want to know more about Gradle is this blog: https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/search/label/Gradle%3AGoodness